# modifying DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use `pandas` to mining data. I have a DataFrame - `data`:

```
   Age  Sex     Name 
0  28   male    Kirill
1  32   female  Alina
2  12   female  Sasha
```

I want to replace `Sex` to digit, instead `male` use `1`, instead `female` - `0`

I try to make in loops:

```
for i in range(data.Age.size()):
    if data.Sex[i]=='male'
        data.Sex[i]=1
    else:
        data.Sex[i]=0
```

But I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.
How I can make it right?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? The new categorical datatype might actually serve you better, depending on your goals beyond this step.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a dict and call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [21]:
sex = {'male':1, 'female':0}
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map(sex)
df

Out[21]:
   Age  Sex    Name
0   28    1  Kirill
1   32    0   Alina
2   12    0   Sasha
```

Or make 2 calls on the masked df:

```
In [25]:
df.loc[df['Sex']=='male','Sex'] = 1
df.loc[df['Sex']=='female','Sex'] = 0
df

Out[25]:
   Age Sex    Name
0   28   1  Kirill
1   32   0   Alina
2   12   0   Sasha
```

In general you should avoid looping over the df when there are vectorised solutions available, additionally it's not a good idea to mutate the container that you're iterating over as it can yield strange behaviour such as it sometimes works or it does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method, which exactly does that:

```
data.replace({'male': 1,
              'female': 0})

   Age  Sex    Name
0   28    1  Kirill
1   32    0   Alina
2   12    0   Sasha
```

or

```
data.replace(["male", "female"], [0, 1])
```

equivalent to:

```
data.replace(to_replace=["male", "female"], values=[0, 1])
```

In that case, lists must have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

To add to their method, if you don't want to explicitly define the dictionary yourself you can better automate the process which comes helpful if you have multiple unique values (i.e. 5+).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sex = np.sort(df['Sex'].unique()) # extract unique values and sorts them alphabetically
sex_dict = dict(enumerate(sex )) # creates a dictionary from the array above
sex_dict= dict(zip(sex_dict.values(), sex_dict.keys())) # Corrects the dictionary

df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map(sex_dict) # maps as described in the other answers.
```

Again, this is more for automating the process for large unique values within the array.

**Orignal DataFrame**

```
   Age     Sex    Name
0   28    male  Kirill
1   32  female   Alina
2   12  female   Sasha
```

**Final Results**

```
   Age  Sex    Name
0   28    1  Kirill
1   32    0   Alina
2   12    0   Sasha
```